# Delete item from arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

In my programm I have a `List of Strings` and a `List of integer values` which should be deleted from the first list. Think of somehing like this:

```
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
items.add("A"); items.add("B"); items.add("C");

ArrayList<Integer> del = new ArrayList<Integer>();
del.add(1); del.add(2);
```

Of course I can loop throught the list with this code and delete the items:

```
for (int i = 0; i < del.size(); i++) 
{
    items.remove(del.get(i));
}
```

But here is the problem. After the first element is deleted the index is shifted so I delete the wrong items. Is there a graceful solution for this?

Comment: Delete in reverse order, remove the higher indices first.

Comment: what is this `ArrayList<Integer> del = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: Of course you are right. Thanks for that. So easy solution...

Comment: `ArrayList<Integer> del = new ArrayList<String>();` <-- this will not compile

Comment: what about checking the item's value?

Comment: you should use a set for the deletion indexes. sets cant contain duplicates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort the deletion list in a descending order and then iterate:

```
Collections.sort(del, Collections.reverseOrder());
for (Integer toDelete : del) {
    // casting to int, because you need #remove(int), not #remove(Object)
    items.remove((int)toDelete);
}
```

[edit] Fixed. Sorry, this was twice reversed at the beginning.

[edit2] Added necessary cast :)

Comment: Great answer, didn't think of that. Also, please note my answer about using a problem domain key instead of the index.

Comment: Question to **edit2**: Shouldn't Java pack/unpack the wrapper by itself?

Comment: No, as there is also a `#remove(Object)` method, this one has precedence, if not casting explicitly; the `#remove(Object)` method would try to remove an `Object` from the list, for which `equals(Object)` is `true`; `#remove(int)` on the other hand removes by index, which is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options, but two of the simpler ones are:

1. Delete the largest indices first. Sort your index list in descending order before you do this.
2. If sorting the index list is not feasible for some reason and your string list doesn't usually contain `null`, first replace all the items you want to delete with `null` then remove all `null`s from the string list (e.g. `while (items.remove(null)) ;`).

Answer (score 0):

Graceful? I don't think so. A working solution would be to make sure your del list is sorted and then go through and decrement all following indexes so they sync back up.

A better solution would be to use a key that is endemic to the problem domain for your deletes instead of the index into the array. That would be a graceful solution.

Comment: Your suggestion about the key is a good one. However, for the first idea, the indexes wouldn't need to be sync'd if the index list was sorted in descending order.